# read and plot multiple txt files in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some output files ie frequency1 .txt , frequency2 .txt and so on (till 21). In each txt files I am having 10 columns and suppose n rows , now I need to plot column 2 and column 3 for all these txt files .I am able to plot for a single txt file

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data=np.loadtxt('frequecy1.txt')
pl.plot(data[:,1],data[:,2],'bo')
X=data[:,1]
Y=data[:,2]
plt.plot(X,Y,':ro')
plt.ylim((0,55000))
plt.show()
```

How would I plot all the files?

Comment: I don't know `numpy` at all, but you could hack this by writing all the data to a single file `with open('path/to/outfile', 'a') as outfile: for infilepath in infilepaths: with open(infilepath) as infile: outfile.write(infile.read()+"\n")` then loading that

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to plot them on the same graph? separate graphs? what's the difference you're trying to achieve between blue and red in your example?

Comment: Actually that happened mistakenly red and blue , I am sorry for that ,I want separate plots for all txt files

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no need to both import pylab and pyplot. Second, if all your files are structured the same, this code should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for fname in ('frequency1.txt', 'frequency2.txt' ...):
    data=np.loadtxt(fname)
    X=data[:,1]
    Y=data[:,2]
    plt.plot(X,Y,':ro')
plt.ylim((0,55000))
plt.show() #or
plt.save('figure.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add something to @Korem's answer. You can create a `list` of filenames then pass it using `for` loop instead of writing file names manually.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filelist=[]

for i in range(1,5):
    filelist.append("frequency%s.dat" %i)

for fname in filelist:
    data=np.loadtxt(fname)
    X=data[:,0]
    Y=data[:,1]
    plt.plot(X,Y,':ro')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
plt.show()
```

use

```
plt.save("chart1.png")
```