# Visualize multiple data in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have multiple output binary files on different files and I want to visualize it on 1 plot. in each file, the file had different rows now I need to visualize it in 1 plot. here's my code:

```
# Visualize training history
import keras
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

for fname in ('/models/unet_mobilenet_jt_0.0001_25_256_yes/unet_mobilenet_jt_0.0001_25_256_yes_history.bin','/models/unet_mobilenet_jt_0.001_50_256_yes/unet_mobilenet_jt_0.001_50_256_yes_history.bin', '/models/unet_mobilenet_jt_0.0001_100_256_yes/unet_mobilenet_jt_0.0001_100_256_yes_history.bin'):
    data=pd.read_pickle(fname)

# Plot training & validat accuray values
plt.plot(data['precision'])
plt.plot(data['val_precision'])
plt.title('Hasil semua epoch precision')
plt.ylabel('precision')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train 25', 'validation 25','train 50', 'validation 50', 'train 100', 'validation 100'], loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

I just can visualize it from train 25 and the rest of the file didn't show up, I've tried from here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725376/read-and-plot-multiple-txt-files-in-python) and it didn't work out

Comment: it's clear, i forgot bout some indent from plt.plo until plt.xlabel had same indent with data=pd.read_pickle(fname)